# Debugging in Eclipse a Cocos2dx application (Cpp)

Tags: c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I'm trying cocos2dx in my windows environment, using eclipse with cdt. I'm able to build the game and play it in my android phone. The problem is I'm not capable of debugging the game. I put a breakpoint in a .cpp file and it is not being reached.

What is going on?

Comment: I don't think debugging the c++ code when running eclipse with Android application is possible. I normally use visual studio to first build a win32 app and there i can easily debug the code and when it is complete, I compile the Android version.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging android apps written in c++,try using the Nvidia NDK debugger. It allows one to set to breakpoints in c++ and debug it at runtime.
You can get it from

https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-debug-manager-android-ndk